# R kableExtra - Having issues with latex

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra

There was a similar post on this, but it did not have the answer I was looking for. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664629/r-markdown-kableextra-package-format-latex-not-working)

I am trying to replicate Hao's example where he does:

````
```{r cars}
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, format = "latex")
```
````

However the output is blank.  When I switch to HTML, it is ok.  I tried creating a PDF, but that didn't work either.

Help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Aksel

Comment: What is it, is it an *.Rmd file? Don't you have a YAML header?

Comment: Yes, it is an Rmd File and have this as the header:                                         ---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:

---

Comment: Without `header-includes: ---` it works for me. `format = "latex"` for PDF , `format = "html"` for HTML.

Comment: I am new at R markdown.  Is there something I need to download to be able to generate these? downloading MacTex.  Perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: Sure, you need a latex installation to create pdfs, I'm using MiKTeX on a windows machine.

Comment: Thank you, will this also allow me to view the table created by kableextra within the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165517/discussion-between-jaysf-and-aksel-etingu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install latex(MaxTeX) on my mac.  Thank you @jafSF.